# Appeasing MyPy trying to use an instance variable

Tags: python, mypy

If I have the file `mypytest/models.py` that looks like this:

```py
from typing import Type


class FakeBaseModel:
    pass


class FakeDatabase:
    Base: Type[FakeBaseModel]

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.Base = FakeBaseModel


db = FakeDatabase()


class FakeModel(db.Base):
    pass
```

And I run `mypy .`, I get the following output:

```
[mypytest {mypytest}]$ mypy .
mypytest/models.py:18: error: Name "db.Base" is not defined
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 2 source files)
```

Clearly, though, `db.Base` is defined. How do I get mypy to recognize it?

Comment: Seems a known bug: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy2-stubs/issues/54 or a unsupported feature: https://github.com/python/mypy/wiki/Unsupported-Python-Features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem here is that `db.Base` is a [variable, not a type alias](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#variables-vs-type-aliases).

It's unclear from your example exactly why you need a dynamic base class. Inlining `FakeBaseModel` would obviously work; you could also just use a type alias while running the type checking:

```py
from typing import Type, TYPE_CHECKING

# *snip*

db = FakeDatabase()

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    FakeBase = FakeBaseModel
else:
    FakeBase = db.Base

class FakeModel(FakeBase):
    pass
```

This will produce valid type checking based on what you've provided (basically, as long as `FakeModel` only uses what's in `FakeBaseModel` so it's safe to treat it as one).

Comment: It is a common pattern for SQLAlchemy. The base model is made using `declarative_base` and is different for each database instance. I've simplified it here to make very clear that the problem is not with sqlalchemy (or sqlalchemy-stubs), rather, it is a problem with mypy.

https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy2-stubs/issues/54

Comment: I think my answer holds, regardless? You should be able to swap in `FakeBaseModel` during type-checking and have mypy be happy.

Comment: Your answer is not what I'm looking for. I want to be able to extend `db.Base` directly, as I believe that syntax is better and _should_ work. If the answer is "mypy doesn't support that", so be it. Not really after a hack, if I just want to appease mypy I could simply do `# type: ignore` or something.

Comment: It _can't_ work per my link at the top of the answer; by definition, a variable will not be used to check types. Using `TYPE_CHECKING` in the way I describe will provide you with valid type-checking modulo the note at the bottom of my answer. Ignoring the type (like with `type: ignore`) will not provide any checking at all.